# Wake on LAN in Windows Susbsystem for Linux

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, windows-terminal, linux-terminal

**How can I wake my Linux machine from WSL?**

My Windows machine has no issue using WOL to wake my Linux machine when using a platform-dedicated software, but when I try doing that from WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04) using the machine's static IP:

```
sudo etherwake -i 192.168.0.99 BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB
```

or using my networks broadcast IP (which I specify in the Windows software):

```
sudo etherwake -i 192.168.0.255 BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB
```

or any of the IPs from `ip route get`, whose function I frankly don't understand:

```
$ ip route get 192.168.0.99
192.168.0.99 via 192.168.144.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.151.115 uid 1000
    cache
```

I get the following error:

```
The target station address is bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb.
SIOCGIFHWADDR on 192.168.0.xx failed: No such device
```

Specyfing the default port as `-p 9` doesn't seem to have any effect.

I have trouble diagnosing if this is a my poor linux skills, poor network knowledge or WSL-related problem I am facing.

Comment: the -i parameter is an interface not an IP address. Then anyway etherwake can only work in LAN so can't be used since the WSL2 isn't in the same LAN: it would have to be bridged, not routed. An other tool (wakeonlan) can work with an IP destination, but the only useful setup would be with a (routed) directed broadcast which is not allowed by default on a router (which would be Windows here). I don't know about Windows but only about Linux so I'm leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Try the command `wakeonlan -i 192.168.0.99 -p 9 <Target MAC>`.

Comment: @harrymc this has a response: `Sending magic packet to 192.168.0.99:9 with BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB` but sadly has no effect on the target machine.

Comment: It's a chicken and eggs problem: if the target is awake, it will receive the IP packet, if it's not awake it won't: because right before it didn't answer the ARP request to find it, even if you yourself know where to find it (BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB). Changes on the router (Windows) must be made in any case.

Comment: @A.B Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I have decided that this requires just too much configuration for my current needs.

Answer (score 2):

> My Windows machine has no issue using WOL to wake my Linux machine when using a platform-dedicated software

That might provide the workaround to do it from within WSL2.

As [@A.B](https://superuser.com/users/639799/a-b) mentioned in the comments (although to use different terminology), WoL works on Layer 2 (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/104760/1210833)).  WSL2 is on a different Layer 2 network (running inside Hyper-V) than your other devices, so the WoL magic broadcast packet can't cross over from WSL2 to your physical device.

But through WSL Interop, we can at least *call* Windows processes from within WSL2, so assuming the Windows software you mentioned above has a commandline interface, you should be able to use *it* directly from WSL2.  Because the Windows executable is running on the Windows network, it should still work fine, even when called from within WSL2.

Another possible solution, since you are running Windows 11 (assuming it is Pro or higher), is to install the WSL Preview release from the Microsoft Store (or from the WSL [releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases) page).  There's a new feature there that allows you to create a separate bridged interface in Hyper-V and use it with WSL2.  I have not tried this myself (I keep meaning to), but see [this blog post](https://randombytes.substack.com/p/bridged-networking-under-wsl?s=r) for some details.

It sounds from your answer that you might have found some info on bridged networking that predated the "official" (albeit preview) support that was added earlier this year.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some digging based on the answers, and came across this source:
https://develmonk.com/2021/06/05/easiest-wsl2-bridge-network-without-hyper-v-virtual-network-manager/

According to which I need to create a bridge. However, even though I recreated some of the steps despite different access route in Windows 11, I decided that it would be counterproductive to set up this much just for having WOL in Windows Terminal.